# Qt installing error (error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: apt, software-installation

I need to install Qt Creator form [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x86-online.run):

So when i install it by this command i get this feedback:

```
so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/Raspberry Pi/Qt$ sudo ./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online.run: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So i tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046555/wkhtmltopdf-libfontconfig-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file) by doing the above command like this:

```
 sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version (2.12.6-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but the libfontconfig1 is installed !!!.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I found that my Ubuntu is X_64 and i have downloaded the X_86, so i am trying downloading the X64 and test it, so this question must be changed to what? (answered,deleted or ...)

Answer (score 0):

Two moments here:

- Qt Creator 4.5.2 may be installed as [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtcreator) as simple as

  ```
  sudo apt-get install qtcreator
  ```
- The binary installer is 32-bit, so you need to install needed 32-bit library with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386
  ```

Comment: thanks but my problem was from x64 instead of x86, which explained at above comment